# Sencha touch select field is looking weird after applying some CSS

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2

My selectfield is looking weird after I applied some CSS. I am applying my CSS to three components:

```
cls: 'txtwhite',
labelCls: 'txtwhite',
inputCls: 'sfborder'
```

My three CSS classes are:

```
.txtwhite {
  font-family:Arial;
  color:white;
  font-size:15px;
  background: #000000;
}

.txtinput {
  font-family:Arial;
  color:white;
  font-size:15px;
  background: #000000;
  border-color: #6E6E6E;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:2px;
}

.sfborder {
  font-family:Arial;
  color:white;
  font-size:15px;
  background: #000000;
  border-color: #0B4C5F;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

My select-box is below the label of the selectfield. On the right side of the select box I am seeing a white colored down arrow (which is the arrow for selecting things from the drop down list) .

My question is: Why is the color of that arrow and some area surrounding it white?